# How to make client-side Java application take different width and height depending on the screen resolutions

Tags: java, resolution

I have a client-side Java application. When I open the application in different screen resolutions, I want the application window take different widths and heights.

In these resolutions:

```
1152x864
1280x800
1280x960
1280x1024
```

the application window should take 944px width & 698px height.

In these resolutions:

```
800x600
1024x768
```

the application window should take 720px width & 530px height.

In these resolutions:

```
1260x600
1280x720
1280x768
1360x768
1366x768
```

the application window should take 944px width & 530px height.

I want to know how this is calculated so I can use it in different applications I am developing.

Comment: Use % for width and height instead of px. Also use floating of elements instead of fixed layout. For this it requires a framework or libary to incorpate

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan No, it sounds like he does mean client-side Java, not HTML.

Comment: you are correct I mean client-side Java

Answer (score 0):

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

With the this code you get the resolution of the screen. Then you can make an "if else" clause to apply the right dimension of your window.

Comment: @JackNew please consider accepting this answer if you feel it sufficiently answered your question.